# Linux :SSH sessions connections getting closed on pkill

Tags: linux, centos6

I inadvertently executed the following command :

```
    pkill -9 tar -xvf
```

I see that all my SSH sessions onto system gets disconnected and ssh deamon also stops. How is the above command affecting SSH sessions?

Comment: Can't test this theory right now but I think what's happening is the options `-xvf` are being interpeted as options to the `pkill` command. The `-v` option inverts the match, so you're killing every process that *isn't* tar. You probably do need the `-f` option (match whole command line), and some kind of quoting like perhaps `pkill -9 -f 'tar -xvf'` (does the check for `-xvf` actually buy you anything anyway?)

Comment: Wumpus is correct. In addition, `pkill` is an extremely dangerous command to run as root and such commands should always be tested with its sister command `pgrep`. (same syntax, less process murder)

Comment: @Wumpus. Thanks. Processes including SSH go down. But I see some processes not in anyway related to tar still active...

Comment: You probably weren't root when you ran it; other surviving processes are ones you didn't have permission to kill.

Comment: @Wumpus The poster mentioned that it killed `sshd` as well, so root is pretty likely. The surviving processes may have been kernel related (enclosed in `[]` brackets).

Comment: But did he mean the master `sshd` process, or the children of it that are handling the individual connections?

Answer (score 1):

According to `pgrep`, running `pgrep tar -xvf` shows *all* processes containing any of those letters in its name. You'd probably want to use the `-f` flag.